# foreach arrays?

Tags: php, foreach, range

Script:

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$ckfile = 'cookie.txt';
foreach (range('a', 'z') as $letters) {
    echo $letters;
}

foreach (range('1', '100') as $numbers) {
    echo $numbers;
}
    $ch = curl_init ("http://site/test.php?letter=".$letters."&page=".$numbers."");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    $output = curl_exec ($ch);

$html = str_get_html(''.$output.'');

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
}
```

As you can see there is three arrays seperated, one by one works, but how them 'put together' in one foreach and do 'job' ?

Etc. I'm not familiar with foreach after all, and if i remember correctly, it's my second time with 'them'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
$ckfile = 'cookie.txt';

foreach (range('a', 'z') as $letters) {
    echo $letters;
    foreach (range('1', '100') as $numbers) {
        echo $numbers;
        $ch = curl_init ("http://site/test.php?letter=".$letters."&page=".$numbers."");
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        $output = curl_exec ($ch);

        $html = str_get_html(''.$output.'');

        foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
           echo $element->href . '<br>';
        }
    }

    echo $numbers;
}
```

But this script will execute for a few minutes... What do you need it for?

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (array_merge($arr1, $arr2, $arr3) as element) { /* do something */ }
```

[`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge)

Comment: With this code @ZeroSuf3r won't be able to send correct requests

Comment: @meze method works, but interesting your's too, saveing somewhere, maybe it help one day, thanks.

Comment: @a.tereschenkov Its not my business to bugfix. The OP asked for a way to iterate over several arrays one after one.